# Problem with reverse computer guessing game

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to make a game that will guess the user's number between 1-19 in five guesses. However, I can't figure out why I can't get to numbers like 3 or 13. It's like it's not storing the lows or highs properly in the while loop. Can anyone help with this?

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string prompt1 = "Is this your number: ";
    string prompt2 = "Correct (1), Too high (2), Too low (3)";
    int count = 0;
    int userInput;
    int high = 19;
    int low = 0;
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    cout << prompt1 << mid << endl;
    ;
    cout << prompt2 << endl;
    cin >> userInput;

    while (userInput != 0 && count < 5)

    {
        if (userInput == 2) {
            int high = mid;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            cout << prompt1 << mid << endl;
            ;
            cout << prompt2 << endl;
            cin >> userInput;
            ++count;
            continue;
        }
        else if (userInput == 3) {
            int low = mid;
            mid = (low + (high + 1)) / 2;
            cout << prompt1 << mid << endl;
            ;
            cout << prompt2 << endl;
            cin >> userInput;
            ++count;
            continue;
        }
        else if (userInput == 1) {
            cout << "Thanks for playing" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Cheater...." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are declaring new variables `high` and `low` in your loop, instead of reassigning the old ones. They get destroyed after that iteration of the loop. So if the guess goes high then low, the updated value of high will not be used after the second guess, instead it will always use `19`.

Comment: Wow all I had to do was delete "int" in the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "iostream"
#define ewhile while

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string prompt1 = "Is this your number: ";
    string prompt2 = "Correct (1), Too high (2), Too low (3)";
    int count=0;
    int userInput;
    int high = 19;
    int low = 0;
    int mid = ( high + low ) / 2;
    cout<< prompt1 << mid <<endl;;
    cout<< prompt2 <<endl;
    cin>> userInput;


    while(userInput!=0 && count < 4)

{
if (userInput == 2)
    {
        high = mid;
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        cout<< prompt1 << mid <<endl;;
        cout<< prompt2 <<endl;
        cin>> userInput;
        ++count;
        continue;
    }
    else if (userInput == 3)
    {
        low = mid;
        mid = (low + (high + 1) ) / 2;
        cout<< prompt1 << mid <<endl;;
        cout<< prompt2 <<endl;
        cin>> userInput;
        ++count;
        continue;
    }
    else if (userInput == 1)
    {
        cout<<"Thanks for playing!"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }


}
        cout<<"Cheater...."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```